# How to persist data search param in url in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on an app which need to fetch data from api and change data on user input. Here the problem is when user first mount the page they should send a default value `monthly` and `2020`. But if user made any changes and if they refresh page it should send user updated data. like if user selected 'half-yearly' and `2018` then on refresh it should send `half-yearly` and `2018`.
I am not sure if it is possible in reacjs or not.

I have tried doing this but it is not working it goes by `monthly` and `2020` every time I refresh page.

Here is my code

```
const DispensingIncidents = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const {
    getFilterData,
    dispensingData,
    getPeriodList,
    getOverviewData,
    location,
    history,
  } = props;

  const [timeSpan, setTimeSpan] = React.useState("Monthly");
  const [year, setYear] = React.useState(2020);
  const [tabValue, setTabValue] = React.useState(0);
  const [spanData, setSpanData] = React.useState([]);
  const { loading, duration, period, dispensingOverviewData } = dispensingData;
  const { count } = dispensingOverviewData;

  useEffect(() => {
    getPeriodList();
  }, [getPeriodList]);

  useEffect(() => {
    history.replace({
      pathname: location.pathname,
      search: `?year=${year}&period=${timeSpan}`,
    });
    setYear(year);
    setTimeSpan(timeSpan);
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [year, timeSpan]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getFilterData(year);
  }, [getFilterData, year]);

  function useQuery() {
    return new URLSearchParams(location.search);
  }
  const query = useQuery();



  // eslint-disable-next-line
  const handleTabChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setTabValue(newValue);
  };

  const handleYearChange = (event) => {
    setYear(event.target.value);
    setTimeSpan(query.get("period"));
  };

  const handleSpanChange = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;

    setTimeSpan(value);
  };

  const time = query.get("period");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (time === "Yearly") {
      const yearlyData = duration["yearly"];
      setSpanData(yearlyData);
    } else if (time === "Weekly") {
      const weeklyData = duration["weekly"];
      setSpanData(weeklyData);
    } else if (time === "Quarterly") {
      const quarterlyData = duration["quarterly"];
      setSpanData(quarterlyData);
    } else if (time === "Monthly") {
      const monthlyData = duration["monthly"];
      setSpanData(monthlyData);
    } else if (time === "6 months") {
      const halfYearlyData = duration["half-yearly"];
      setSpanData(halfYearlyData);
    }
  }, [time, duration]);
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: I suppose you have an API to set the inputs data and one for get the last saved data ?

Comment: I dont have api to get last save data i am just store the user selected data to url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you'd need one function to decode your URL params and one to encode them and sync your state's value and the URL params.

```
const valueFromURL = decodeYourURLParams(window.location.search)
const [valuesYouExpect, setValuesYouExpect] = useState(valueFromURL);

// or setting your state in useEffect if it's more proper
```

You would need to be able to pass params to your `getPeriodList()` function to append the params to your API call.

```
useEffect(() => {
   getPeriodList(decodeYourURLParams(window.location.search); // for instance
}, [getPeriodList, valuesYouExpect]);
```

Then whenever the user changes the value, create a new URL and push a new state to `history`

```
function updateValues(newValues) {
  const updatedValues = { ...valuesYouExpect, ...newValues };
  const { pathname, origin } = window.location;
  const newURL = `${origin}${pathname}?${encodeYourUrlParams(updatedValues)}`;

  // now change the URL
  window.history.replaceState({}, '', newURL);

  updateStateValues(updatedValues);
```

Now when your value are updated, `history` is updated and it triggers a call to the API with your params.

And also when your refresh params set in the URL get passed to your component.

Answer (score 2):

When you refresh the page, all data that you have in your app, e.g. state, props, redux state, etc. is gone.
There are several ways to keep the data:

- store it on the backend
- store it in the localStorage as pointed out in the comment above
- store it in the cookies

When you start your app (e.g. after refresh) you should check whether you have previously saved the data anywhere. Then you set it as default value in the hook

Answer (score 0):

Well, talking about refreshing the whole page, I suppose you could use localStorage, either the react-ey way like the one from [useHooks](https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/) or natively as explained on [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/localstorage).